# How can I get Tomcat's logging.properties to recognize my Catalina variables?

Tags: variables, properties, log4j, tomcat7, catalina

We have several `Tomcat 7` instances installed on different servers.  We sometimes deploy basically the same app to different Tomcats (for different customers) with the only differences being configs.  In an effort to standardize logging locations, etc., we are trying to make the apps "universal" so that simply deploying the war file to a Tomcat instance will wire it up automatically so that we don't have to remember to change app for customer 1 and then again for customer 2, etc.

Anyway, in each `Tomcat/conf` folder, I have added some properties to the end of the `catalina.properties` file.  Example:

```
# custom logging
log.base=c:/logs/tomcat/myapp
log.file=MYAPP.log
```

Now, in my **application's** `log4j.cfg` file, I have:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${log.base}/${log.file}
```

And in my **application's** `myapp.cfg` I have:

```
logfile=${log.file}
```

Works great when I deploy.  Tomcat puts everything where it should be **except** what's in the `logging.properties` file.

That file normally contains:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
```

But I want to change the `${catalina.base}/logs` to use my own `${log.base}` variable.  But Tomcat (or perhaps log4j?) doesn't recognize this.  Instead, it actually creates a directory named "${log.base}" in the Tomcat root folder.

I read that you can declare custom variables in a `setenv.bat` file.  I did that and it still didn't work.

How can I fix this?

BTW, I am using Windows, Tomcat 7 and the Windows service install (with the GUI).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Set the environment variable JAVA_OPTS in setenv.bat. In this way you give a java VM argument. The following works in setenv.sh in Linux:

export JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog.base=/logs/tomcat/"

Now you should be able to use ${log.base} in logging.properties